# setState React issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have an issue with setState in React component.
I'm trying to update the state of advSearch in `componentDidMount` method - but the state does not change at all. Here I send the code:

```
class BookList extends Component {
state = {
books: [],
advSearch: {
  author: "",
  title: "",
  category: "",
  year: "",
  isbn: ""
}
};

componentDidMount() {


console.log(this.props.match.path.substring(1, 9));
if (this.props.match.path.substring(1, 9) === "advanced") {
  this.setState({
    advSearch: {
      author: this.props.match.params.author,
      title: this.props.match.params.title,
      category: this.props.match.params.category,
      year: this.props.match.params.year,
      isbn: this.props.match.params.isbn
    }
  });
```

The code passes the above if statement in my scenario.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: What do you mean the state didn't change at all? Where did you test/log to verify the state hasn't changed? Did you `console.log()` inside the if statement to ensure that `this.setState()` was being called. Did you add debug inside the component such as `<div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>` to see if the state was indeed being updated?

Comment: Yes, I verified it with `console.log`, the state od `advSearch` stays the same

Comment: Where did you place the `console.log()`? Please place `<div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>` in the render method, and verify that they aren't being set.

Comment: before setting the state please verfiy you have data in `this.props.match.params`

Comment: Okay, this is extremely weird, I use `console.log` which gives me different values than the `<div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}` - in the latter one the state does updated ...

Comment: changing state is not synchronous operation, if you place console log after this.setState it will have old values

Comment: That is probably because your console.log gets printed before the setState execution has been completed.

Comment: Exactly! I solved the problem by changing the code with using the callback function from the setState method. All works great now - thank you very much!

Comment: also typically it's unexpected to `setState` in `componentDidMount`. better specify state initialization in `constructor` that would be synchronous

Comment: I would  recommend to use chrome and download the official react extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi This way you can always see your components states without console.logging anything